# Получить заголовок HTTP запроса с Winhttp (winapi)

Tags: winapi, http, winhttp

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу понять, почему так происходит:

Пытаюсь получить header заголовок hhtp ответа от сервера: Использую функцию из Winhttp - WinHttpQueryHeaders:

```
DWORD dwSize = 0;           //Сюда функция занесет значение кол-ва байт в прочитанном заголовке
VOID* lpOutBuffer = NULL;   //Сюда функция поместить указатель на массив данных прочитанного заголовка

//Первоначально вызовем функцию для определения кол-ва байт в заголовке(4ый параметр NULL):
BOOL my_WinHttpQueryHeaders = WinHttpQueryHeaders(my_WinHttpOpenRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, NULL, &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);


lpOutBuffer = new char[dwSize]; //Выделим буффер под данные заголовка.


//И опять вызовем функцию (4ый параметр уже указатель lpOutBuffer)
my_WinHttpQueryHeaders = WinHttpQueryHeaders(my_WinHttpOpenRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, lpOutBuffer, &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);

//lpOutBuffer - тут данные заголовка
```

И вроде бы все нормально, данные в lpOutBuffer, но они идут через байт, то есть первый символ в 0-элементе, второй символ во 2ом элементе, 3 символ в 5ом, а между ними пустые байты.

Хотя ответ от сервера по поводу кодировки: charset=utf-8

Да и вообще заголовок http - может состоять только из ASCII символов.

Не пойму что за особенность такая ? То есть функция возвращает значения в dwSize - минимум в 2 раза больший, чем содержится в заголовке реальных символов. И соответственно заполняет буффер через байт.

Comment: а как вы это определяете?

Comment: наверное потому, что у тебя функция данные получает в многобайтовой кодировке/unicod'e, которая в конец заканчивается двойным нуллом. Либо вызывай явно анси-версию с буквой А в конец имени функции, либо преобразуй результат функцией типа WideCharToMultiByte. ответ сервера и буфер, который тебе вернет винапи могут быть в разных кодировках. если функция с W на конце, то используется 2х байтовые символы. в UTF-8 их еще надо преобразовать.

Comment: W или A версия функций используется определяется настройками проекта. по умолчанию уже очень давно, стоит использовать юникод, т.е. реальное имя функции заменяется на тоже +W в конец. и функция от тебя ожидает строковые аргументы с типом wchar_t - т.е. строки двухбайтовые.

Comment: Yakov, так у функции WinHttpQueryHeaders нет версий А или W. Или я плохо ищу ? Вы видели такие версии ?

Comment: timur, определяю так: просто вывожу через цикл поэлементно каждый элемент буфера lpOutBuffer.